# Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and suppose that $A$ is a subset of $X$. If $Bd(A) = \emptyset$ then A =∅ or $A = X$ .

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and suppose that $A$ is a subset of $X$. If $Bd(A) = \emptyset$ then $A = \emptyset$ or $A = X$.

I am studying introduction to proofs and we have learned set theory and a basic introduction to topology in order to write proofs.

Here are my definitions for this problem:

Let $(X,\mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$. A point $x \in X$ is in the boundary of $A$ if every open set containing $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X−A$

I have an example which demonstrates one of the conditions: Let $X = \mathbb R$ and $\mathfrak T = \{U \subseteq \mathbb R: 1 \in U$ or $U = \emptyset \}$ Let $ A =\{3,4\}$ Then $Bd(A) = \{3,4\}$ based on this definition  I think this is a true statement so I know need to prove it.  All of my proofs for topology involve sets and elements of sets.  I only have a basic, introduction to topology.

As far as a proof goes I was thinking about a proof by contraction? But I do not know if that is a good way to go about it.

Proof: Assume $Bd(A) \neq  \emptyset$ and $A = \emptyset$ or $A =X$ then there exists an $x \in X$ and therefore $x \in A$  therefore $A \neq \emptyset$.

Am I on the right track? How do I show the second condition $X = A$?

Comment: It's an interesting topology in your example.  But one rather pathological example shouldn't convince you that the general result is true.  It's not completely obvious

Comment: Assuming that $\operatorname{Bd}(A)\neq \emptyset$, is wrong, since this is part of the setting of the excercise (the same mistake would be assuming that $A$ is not a subset of $X$, for example). If you want a proof by contradiction, you must assume that given conditions do not imply $A = \emptyset$ or $A = X$, that is, you are (additionaly) assuming that $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A\neq X$.

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, the statement is actually not true - without another assumption like connectedness - so you see what I mean about jumping to conclusions from one example.

Comment: @GregoryGrant is there example that shows this is not true?

Answer (score 2):

The topology space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ should be connected. For a subset $A\subset X$ we have $Bd(A)=Cl(A)-A^{0}$. So, if $Bd(A)=\emptyset\Rightarrow Cl(A)=A^{0}=A$ Then $A$ is both open and closed. Since $X$ is connected, we have $A=X$ or $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Right I was just thinking that, if the space had two components like $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ then the boundary of $(0,1)$ is indeed empty.

Comment: What is the definition of $A^0$ used here?

Comment: $A^\circ$ is the interior of $A$, the union of all open sets contained in $A$.

Comment: @Uncountable the interior of A.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yeh, other assumptions must be added.

Comment: Ah ok, this answer looks pretty sound then, since we have connectedness iff $X$ and $\emptyset$ are the only sets that are both closed and open, so connectedness is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: We have never learned "connected".  I do know the definition of boundary you have given.

Comment: You can see this. [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space

Comment: Should I be adding other conditions? I am sorry but I follow for showing $Cl(A) = A$ but without using connected how do I show that $A$ could be the empty?

Comment: Your assumption in this proposition can help us conclude $Cl(A)=A^{0}=A$ i.e. $A$ is both open and closed, we should add other assumptions to guarantee that both open and closed set is empty or is $X$ and connectedness is a good condition.

Comment: I guess I am trying to ask how I can prove this without connectedness as we have never discussed this in my class. Without connectedness is this a false statement?

Comment: Without connectedness, the statement is actually not true.

Comment: Do you have an example of a set that shows this then?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace I posted an example above, if $X=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ (open intervals in $\mathbb R$) and $A=(0,1)$ then the boundary of $A$ is the empty set.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!